# Replace placeholders in string with replacements sequence

Tags: python

I have a location string with placeholders, used as '#'. Another string which are replacements for the placeholders. I want to replace them sequentially, (like format specifiers). What is the way to do it in Python?

```
location = '/tmp/#/dir1/#/some_dirx/dir/var/2/#/dir3'
replacements = 'xyz'

result = '/tmp/x/dir1/y/some_dirx/dir/var/2/z/dir3'
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string replace", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: I am not using the same replacement string for every replacement.

Comment: Understood -- you replace each occurrence in turn.  Where are you stuck?  You've shown no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Where did `somedir` go? I mean the expected output does not match your the definition

Comment: My bad, corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method of a string as follows:

```py
for replacement in replacements:
    location = location.replace('#', replacement, 1)
```

It is important you use the third argument, `count`, in order to replace that placeholder just once. Otherwise, it will replace every time you find your placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If your location string does not contains format specifiers (`{}`) you could do:

```
location = '/tmp/#/dir1/#/some_dirx/dir/var/2/#/dir3'
replacements='xyz'
print(location.replace("#", "{}").format(*replacements))
```

**Output**

```
/tmp/x/dir1/y/some_dirx/dir/var/2/z/dir3
```

As an alternative you could use the fact that repl in [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can be a function:

```
import re
from itertools import count

location = '/tmp/#/dir1/#/some_dirx/dir/var/2/#/dir3'


def repl(match, replacements='xyz', index=count()):
    return replacements[next(index)]


print(re.sub('#', repl, location))
```

**Output**

```
/tmp/x/dir1/y/some_dirx/dir/var/2/z/dir3
```